# anaconda-navigator won't launch with UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: anaconda, conda

## Problem description:

After a reboot, the command $ anaconda-navigator will no longer launch the Anaconda Navigator.

Instead the following tracestack is generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 99, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.logs import clean_logs
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/logs.py", line 18, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config import (LOG_FILENAME, LOG_FOLDER,
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config.main import CONF
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/main.py", line 67, in <module>
    raw_mode=True,
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.load_from_ini()
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 279, in load_from_ini
    self.read(self.filename(), encoding='utf-8')
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 697, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1015, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

## Troubleshooting attempts

### First, I have tried:

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
anaconda-navigator
```

Based on comments at:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1580

### Next, I have tried:

```
$ anaconda-navigator --reset
```

However that results in:

Anaconda Navigator configuration reset...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 75, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.config import CONF_PATH
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config.main import CONF
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/main.py", line 67, in <module>
    raw_mode=True,
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.load_from_ini()
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 279, in load_from_ini
    self.read(self.filename(), encoding='utf-8')
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 697, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1015, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/home/penguin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: @Cœur Done. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## Troubleshooting

First, try resetting Navigator.

```
$ anaconda-navigator --reset
```

The above command should remove corrupted log files at ~/.anaconda, but if this does not work or results in an error, try removing the log files manually.

```
$ rm -rf /home/$USER/.anaconda
```

Finally if that doesn't work try:

```
$ conda install anaconda-clean
$ conda-clean --yes
```

## Reference

@goanpeca and @jeethjoseph's comments at: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/7256